# Find the limit $\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{\left( \left( e+1\right) ^{\ln \left( e^x+1\right)} - \left( e+1\right) ^x\right)} $

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Find without using De L'Hospital's rule the following limit:
>
> $$\lim_\limits{x\to +\infty}{\left( \left( e+1\right) ^{\ln \left( e^x+1\right)} - \left( e+1\right) ^x\right)} $$

I have tried to factorize it but I always seem to end up with an indeterminate form... How can I do it with using DLH?

Please don't use approximations because I haven't "officially" learnt them yet...

Comment: Hint: Write $\log(e^x+1)=x+\log(1+e^{-x})$

Comment: @tired how do you prove this without approximations?

Comment: general rules for logarithms

Comment: @tired This leads to the indeterminate form $\infty\cdot 0$...

Comment: Since $a=\ln(e+1)>1$, $e^u-1\sim u$ when $u\to0$ and $\ln(1+v)\sim v$ when $v\to0$, $$e^{a\ln(e^x+1)}-e^{ax}=e^{ax}(e^{a\ln(1+e^{-x})}-1)\sim e^{ax}a\ln(1+e^{-x})\sim e^{ax}ae^{-x}\to+\infty.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If no L'Hopital and asymptotics are allowed then we need some kind of "standard" limits to be used. For example, if we know the derivatives of $\ln x$ and $a^x$ at zero then we can write by the derivative definition
\begin{align}
&\frac{\ln(1+h)}{h}\to 1,\tag{1}\\
&\frac{a^h-1}{h}\to\ln a\tag{2}
\end{align}
as $h\to 0$.

Now denote $a=e+1$ and factor out $a^x$ to get
$$
\Bigl(a^{\ln(1+e^{-x})}-1\Bigr)a^x=\underbrace{\frac{a^{\ln(1+e^{-x})}-1}{\ln(1+e^{-x})}}_{\to\ln a\  \text{ (by (2))}}\cdot \underbrace{\frac{\ln(1+e^{-x})}{e^{-x}}}_{\to 1\ \text{ (by (1))}}\cdot \underbrace{e^{-x}a^x}_{\to\infty}\to\infty.
$$

Comment: I don't know where the error is, but from the graph of the function we can see that the limit as x tends to positive infinity is 0, thus your claim must be wrong somewhere...

Comment: @Jason no way this goes to zero ...

Comment: @Jason $e^{-x}a^x=\Bigl(\frac{e+1}{e}\Bigr)^x\to\infty$

Comment: @Jason This is a good example that one should not trust numerical calculations in indeterminate cases because they are unstable. Don't you think it looks very suspicious that such a nice smooth function suddenly drops down from very large values to zero in no time? You can even try much simpler function $\ln(1+e^{-x})e^{2x}\to\infty$ with the same "strange" behaviour at $x\ge 37$, but easier limit calculation.

Comment: @Jason that is just because computer programms don't diggest large numbers :D . Looking at your original equation in recognizing that $\log(e^x+1)>x$ it is immedeatly clear that this thing has to explode...